# MySQL service not starting on WAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

I donwloaded the latest version of WAMP which is 3.0.6 and I am at my wits end with this. The Apache services works 100% but the MySQL service on WAMP refuses to start and I have tried several solutions found on stackoverflow. Here is what I have tried:

- I tried changing the port from 3306 to 3307 (and others within the 330X range), and when I test the port, it just says `Port 3307 is not found associated with TCP protocol`. Even for the default 3306 port it says this
- I tried checking the MySQL logs but it comes up as a blank document
- I tried starting the wampmysqld64 service in Services.msc and it fails
- I checked for any duplicate my.ini files on my system and there are none
- I uninstalled XAMPP, but that didn't fix anything
- I tried disabling my firewalls
- I tried manually changing the port numbers in the my.ini file
- I tried a tutorial on YouTube that used the MySQL console on WAMP but whenever I try that it asks for a password and closes after I try to proceed beyond that point
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling WAMP several times
- I have restarted WAMP and my computer after each change I made
- I saw a few resources said to delete certain files from mysql/data but I do not have a data folder in my mysql directory in wamp
- I don't have any ib_logfiles or ibdata files to delete
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the MySQL service
- I can't delete anything from the mysql-bin.index file because it does not exist anywhere in my wamp folder
- I tried using the option `Use port other than 3306` and changing it from 3301 - 3309, none of them work
- I tried running wampserver64 as an administrator
- I tried installing WAMP as an administrator
- I checked my Microsoft C/C++ Runtime Libraries and have all the required libraries
- Lastly, a friend of mine downloaded the same version as me and has the exact same configurations as me but his WAMP works perfectly fine.

What else can I try to get the MySQL service to run on WAMP?

Comment: remove WAMP and install `apache` `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` separately , it may fix your problem

Comment: I guess you already tried to run it as administrator?

Comment: Look at the _Windows Event Viewer_ for error messages from MYSQL. MySQL Writes to that log before opening its own text log file and the error messages are usually pretty self explanitory

Comment: BIG NOTE: You have to install WAMPServer as an Administrator. If you did not do that, then uninstall WAMPServer and then manually delete the `C:\wamp` folder. Then try re-installing again, but run the installer using the `Run as Administrator` option

Comment: Also check [this post on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) and make sure you have ALL the required Microsoft C/C++ Runtime Libraries installed

Comment: @simon Yes I have

Comment: @RiggsFolly The Windows Event Viewer just says the service keeps aborting, I tried your suggestion of reinstalling WAMPServer as administrator, and I checked and confirmed I have all the required runtime libraries...it's still not working

Comment: Are you using other software like mysql workbench or some other possible service in your pc that may work as mysql server?

Comment: @Periback yes I do and I tried disabling the service and it still did not work

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with wamp server 3.1.3 and already tried most of the technique what is mentioned in the above question. Please suggest if anybody found any solution.

Comment: I also faced same issue and rectified by myself. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352449/how-to-resolve-mysql-port-3306-error-on-wamp/52448840#52448840)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and after trying a lot of possible solutions, I solved it by the following steps:

1. Make a backup of MySQL data folder (*C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\data*).
2. Make a clean WAMP installation on another PC or Windows installation.
3. Copy the following folders/files from the clean installation and paste it 
   to the corrupt installation.

   - C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\data\mysql
   - C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\data\sys
   - C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\data\auto.cnf
4. Delete the following files from the installation where you have the problem:

   - **.err
   - **.pid
   - ib_logfile0
   - ib_logfile1

On completion of the above I also restarted WAMP services and it started working fine for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was caused by the MySQL service already running and blocking port 3306, it was solved by stopping the MySQL (or could be MariaDB) service in Windows

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reconnect to the port using MySQL Installer. After everything is installed, the last step is the settings, click on RECONFIGURE, on MySQL Server, follow the steps it gives by Default, on the Windos Service tab, check the option => "Start the MySQL Server at System Startup", go ahead , and enter your root password, and proceed. Then try to reconnect. It worked for me, hope it helps.

Hope this helps

Comment: Rather than using images, consider typing out these instructions and providing further clarity on what they do.

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be caused by another application using the same ports as MySQL, thus resulting in a conflict. Specifically, in my experience, I've implicated Skype as the culprit.

You can check and turn it off by opening Skype, going to Tools → Options → Advanced → Connections, and then unchecking the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".

I've seen this solve the problem on at least one occasion.

Comment: I don't have Skype on my laptop

Answer (score -1):

I faced the exact issue and I found that the problem is with WAMP server app. So I downloaded version 2.5 and it works perfectly for me.